# NodeJs Authentication????

Tags: node.js, session, authentication

I'm building a apllication with NodeJs. My app have 1 login form.

When **user A** login successfully, I save username in session of Express.

And now I want when another user is **B**, login with that username, the **user A** 'll be **logout**, he 'll have a messager alert 'This account was login in another place' and **user B** is **login**.

Anyone can help me please. Thanks

Comment: I don't have any idea for this. So can you help me?

Comment: What are you using to control the authentication process?

Comment: Another user from same device, browser?

Answer (score 5):

Save the  the user in for example a database, create a token for the specific login session and add this to the user in de database. Switch this token each login.

With each request check the authentication token (you can store tokens in local storage), then you can check if the token is up to date (active) or not.

Once another user logs in the token will change, and so on.

If you want the logout to happen without making a request you will need to use socket.io